# Static IPv4 and dynamic IPv6 on same interface

Tags: centos, dhcp, ipv6, static-ip, ipv4

I am trying to set up a CentOS 5.4 box to use a static IPv4 address, while getting a dynamic IPv6 address at boot time.

I have only one interface, apart from the loopback interface, `eth0`. It has a static v4 and internet connectivity (I can SSH in). However, it doesn't get an IPv6 by default.

I have enabled IPv6 in `/etc/sysconfig/network` and I have added `IPV6INIT=yes` to the config in `/etc/sysconfig/networking/devices/`.

If I use dhcp6c it does get a valid IPv6 address, but the main question is how do I configure it to get one at boot-time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end, the answer is simple. One has to put several options in the `/etc/sysconfig/networking/devices/` files.

The first is `IPV6INIT=yes`, obviously, to enable IPv6 on that interface. Now, to enable DHCPv6 so you get an adress at boot time, you also have to add `DHCPV6C=yes`. That fixed it for me.

So you have at least these two lines:

> IPV6INIT=yes
>   DHCPV6C=yes

That's it :-)

Answer (score 2):

The first step would be to check if the interface is getting the default link-local `fe00:*` and any-cast`ff00:` addresses.

If you are not using dhcp6 (and i personally prefer not to) then you need to configure the router to broadcast teh default routs etc. perhaps you have already done this?

You can use the `radvdump` program to verify that the router is sending advertisements and they are getting to this box.

Comment: It does get a link-local address, this is not the problem. Due to the infrastructure of the network I need dchp6c. There is no ra daemon running on our network.

Comment: if you see the link local addresses then ip6 is basically working. The RA stuff wont help you, though I will leave it in for others who come across this question.